# why ef core FisrtOrDefault() will call the entity parameter constructor?

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

sorry,i am not very good at english!!

i am using ef core 3.1.4,i just don't understand

- why the 【IQueryable.FirstOrDefault() 】 method will call the entity
  paramter constructor?
- what is the mapping rule?

*the result and code is here:*

### Program.cs Result

[image]

### **Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using IdentityClient.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace IdentityClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("db"));
            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var writeContext = provider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            var admin = new UserEntity("admin", "admin123");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(admin));
            writeContext.User.Add(admin);
            writeContext.SaveChanges();

            var readContext = provider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            var user = readContext.User.FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(user == null ? "" : JsonSerializer.Serialize(user));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

### MyDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace IdentityClient.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<UserEntity> User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### UserEntity.cs

```
using System;

namespace IdentityClient.Data
{
    public class UserEntity
    {
        //1.why query will call the constructor?
        public UserEntity(string name, string password) {
            Id=Guid.NewGuid();
            Name = name;
            Salt = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            //2.why [Password] is different,what is the rule
            Password = Salt;
        }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Salt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Why query will call the constructor?**

> Starting with EF Core 2.1, it is now possible to define a constructor
> with parameters and have EF Core call this constructor when creating
> an instance of the entity. The constructor parameters can be bound to
> mapped properties, or to various kinds of services to facilitate
> behaviors like lazy-loading.
>
> When EF Core creates instances of these types, such as for the results
> of a query, it will first call the default parameterless constructor
> and then set each property to the value from the database. However, if
> EF Core finds a parameterized constructor with parameter names and
> types that match those of mapped properties, then it will instead call
> the parameterized constructor with values for those properties and
> will not set each property explicitly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors

**2. Why [Password] is different, what is the rule?**

Based on the Microsoft documentation you can map query results to entity properties by this convention:

> The parameter types and names must match property types and names,
> except that properties can be Pascal-cased while the parameters are
> camel-cased.

If you don't accept the parameter for a specific property it will map implicitly. so Salt fills from query and Password fills in the constructor.

**Postscript**: Being set property by another property in the constructor is not a good practice. because the order of declaration or statements could impact the final result. for example In your case when you change lines 19,20 with each other in [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fKux72) you will get the expected result, and it's a bad smell in your code.

[image]

Comment: thanks,body,i got it.if i write a default parameterless constructor,everything is good.and your [PostScript] i don't understand

Comment: shortly I mean that using the reference of another object's property(line 15) makes your code complicated by unpredictable behavior especially when you are using EF Core). then I gave an example by the code snippet that if you change the order of property declaration(in lines 19,20) you get a different result. and it implies that your code is not solid and stable enough. explaining why it happens needs an article.